# Why is SpaceShipTwo's nozzle scarfed?

Tags: propulsion, nozzle, virgin-galactic

As seen in this photo (from [here](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/08/20/virgin-galactics-rocket-man)) there appears to be a significant scarf to the nozzle.

[image]

I'm familiar with scarfing reaction control jet nozzles to fit fuselage contours, but this one is completely external.

It's possible the image of the nozzle is distorted by the camera lens but I don't think so; the aft bulkhead of the fuselage appears perfectly circular.

It is also possible that the nozzle has been vectored up, but I don't think SpaceShipTwo has thrust vectoring, and the exhaust streaks inside the nozzle appear to be aligned with the longitudinal axis of the spacecraft.

Comment: It's free pitch-up force for SS2's trajectory design.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting to see how much the aft fuselage design has changed since that other question was asked.  Not free though, it takes away from the X axis force.

Comment: Well, so would gimbaling or any other TVC system.

Comment: Sure.  There is no free lunch.